# Numeric text list to parent/children elements

Tags: algorithm, list, parent, hierarchy, children

I have text file that looks like this:

```
1. Apple
1.1. Apricot
1.2. Avocado
1.2.1. Banana
1.2.1.2. Blackberry
1.2.2. Boysenberry
1.3. Cherry
1.4. Dragonfruit
1.5. Plantain
1.5.1. Pear
1.5.1.1. Pomelo
```

And so on.

I need hierarchy array with children / parents elements from this simple text input.

Iam stuck with this, need help.

Comment: In what language do you want to do this? Have you attempted it?

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the hierarchy as a list of dictionaries in python. The list would like like this:

```
[{'id': '1', 'parent': '0', 'name': 'Apple'},
{'id': '1.1', 'parent': '1', 'name': 'Apricot'},
{'id': '1.2', 'parent': '1', 'name': 'Avocado'},
{'id': '1.2.1', 'parent': '1.2', 'name': 'Banana'},
{'id': '1.2.1.2', 'parent': '1.2.1', 'name': 'Blackberry'},
{'id': '1.2.2', 'parent': '1.2', 'name': 'Boysenberry'},
{'id': '1.3', 'parent': '1', 'name': 'Cherry'},
{'id': '1.4', 'parent': '1', 'name': 'Dragonfruit'},
{'id': '1.5', 'parent': '1', 'name': 'Plantain'},
{'id': '1.5.1', 'parent': '1.5', 'name': 'Pear'},
{'id': '1.5.1.1', 'parent': '1.5.1', 'name': 'Pomelo'}]
```

Here, each dictionary inside the list represents each row in the text file. The row contains the id, its parent and the associated name.

Code for reproducing the list of dictionaries (Stack.txt contains the text file in the question):

```
res = []

with open("Stack.txt","r") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        var = str(line)
        var = var.rstrip('\n')
        var = var.split(' ')
        dic = {}
        if var[0] == "1.":
            dic["parent"] = "0"
            dic["id"] = "1"
            dic["name"] = var[1]
            res.append(dic)
        else:
            temp = var[0][:-1]
            id =  temp[-1]
            parent = temp[:-2]
            id = parent + "." + id
            dic["parent"] = parent
            dic["id"] = id
            dic["name"] = var[1]
            res.append(dic)

fin.close()
for x in res:
    print x
```